# Windows 8 freezes for second in every couple of seconds

Tags: windows-8, laptop, freeze

So there is a video link
My laptop looses focus, while I am typing in any editor it stops for a second and its like hangs and then after second it runs. It keeps happening.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1j2oazv2o6qn29p/lappyfreez.mp4?dl=0

**Memory:**
[image]

**CPU:**
[image]

Solution:
I did a disk check and required repair of my c drive. There are two ways to do it. 
1. Go to c drive -> Right click -> tools -> Check. when prompted that errors ->Do repair by clicking.
2. Use command prompt. run as administer -> chkdsk c: /r -> restart.

It took around 1.5 hours. The problem stopped. The processes are running faster and smoother.
Finally the Disk graph was most of constant less peaks and downs. The read & write speeds were more.

Comment: I am willing to make this statement.  Almost all "my operating freezes for a couple second" problem, I have seen, are caused by windows waiting on a storage device I/O event to happen.

Comment: which "storage device I/O event"? how can I debug ? at this time only mouse & earphone is connected.

Comment: You would need to determine which storage device is failing.  You have more then just a mouse and headset connected since your laptop boots into an operating system.  This means at the very least you have a keyboard connected also.  It also means you have a primary HDD.

Comment: I have added some images of my CPU and memory.from task manager does something looks fishy ?

Comment: Hey its solved just clicked on C drive and did a disk check and repair. windows restarted repair done. and working fine.

Comment: Since that worked; plan to replace the drive: it's starting to fail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20312/discussion-between-user3217310-and-ramhound).

Comment: How can I avoid this ? I want the my disk keep working good for long time ? I don't have budget to replace it in near future.

Comment: Avoid what? your drive is going to fail, eventually data loss will happen, it's only a matter of time. Most drives have multi-year warranties take advantage of them